# Getting issue "Repository test has failure" while trying to import project from bitbucket into android studio

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-studio

While i'm trying to import a project from bitbucket into android studio[ windows 8], getting issue -"Repository test has failed". I am not able figure out what is the problem. If anyone having knowledge regarding this,please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last i have solved this issue. There was problem with ssh key. Any how the old ssh key was not working properly. I have created ssh key with help of eclipse and used in bitbucket.